# I can't figure out why i'm getting Run-time error '1004' Method 'Worksheets' of object' _Global failed

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to vba and have not touched it before till now. I am supposed to troubleshoot why this program works on 1 computer but doesn't work on another. I have googled a few solutions but none of them worked for me. I do not understand how i am getting the error at the range line. Can anyone enlighten me?

Here is part of my code:

```
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
SQLStr = xxx 
rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic

Dim myArray()

myArray = rs.GetRows()

kolumner = UBound(myArray, 1)
rader = UBound(myArray, 2)

For K = 0 To kolumner ' Using For loop data are displayed
    Range("A1").Offset(0, K).Value = rs.Fields(K).Name
    For R = 0 To rader
       Range("A1").Offset(R + 1, K).Value = myArray(K, R)
    Next
Next

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Cn.Close
Set Cn = Nothing
```

Comment: This code does not use the method 'Worksheets'.

Comment: That might fail if the active sheet isn't a worksheet (eg it's a chart sheet).  Your code needs to be more specific about where the data should be placed - ie. use an explicit worksheet object.